# add Zoom controls of Camera in Camera

Tags: android, camera

I am making a Camera application in which i am using Surface View for camera and all other stuffs. I took the guidelines from the following link.

http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/43414.aspx

Now everything works fine but the problem is that i cant see any Zoom Controls and Brightness Controls in the camera. How to set that please Guide me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10):

In your camera layout add ZoomControls.

```
<ZoomControls
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/surface_camera"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:id="@+id/CAMERA_ZOOM_CONTROLS">
</ZoomControls>
```

add these variables to your cameraActivity

```
int currentZoomLevel = 0, maxZoomLevel = 0;
```

Then add following code to your surfaceChanged method.

```
    ZoomControls zoomControls = (ZoomControls) findViewById(R.id.CAMERA_ZOOM_CONTROLS);

    if(params.isZoomSupported()){    
    maxZoomLevel = params.getMaxZoom();

    zoomControls.setIsZoomInEnabled(true);
        zoomControls.setIsZoomOutEnabled(true);

        zoomControls.setOnZoomInClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                    if(currentZoomLevel < MAX_ZOOM){
                        currentZoomLevel++;
                        camera.startSmoothZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                    }
            }
        });

    zoomControls.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                    if(currentZoomLevel > 0){
                        currentZoomLevel--;
                        camera.startSmoothZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                    }
            }
        });    
   }
   else
     zoomControls.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: have at look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235511/camera-zoom-in-out-functionality-in-custom-camera-null-pointer-exception question, using your solution

Answer (score 2):

add these variables to your Activity Class

```
int currentZoomLevel = 0, maxZoomLevel = 0;
private Parameters params;
private Camera mCamera;
private LayoutInflater controlInflater = null;
```

add to your onCreate Method

```
controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
    View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
    LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                                                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);

         ZoomControls zoomControls = (ZoomControls) findViewById(R.id.zoomControls1);        

         if (params.isZoomSupported()) {
         final int maxZoomLevel = params.getMaxZoom();
         Log.i("max ZOOM ", "is " + maxZoomLevel);
         zoomControls.setIsZoomInEnabled(true);
         zoomControls.setIsZoomOutEnabled(true);

         zoomControls.setOnZoomInClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
         public void onClick(View v){
         if(currentZoomLevel < maxZoomLevel){
         currentZoomLevel++;
         //mCamera.startSmoothZoom(currentZoomLevel);
         params.setZoom(currentZoomLevel);
         mCamera.setParameters(params);
         }
         }
         });

         zoomControls.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
         public void onClick(View v){
         if(currentZoomLevel > 0){
         currentZoomLevel--;
         params.setZoom(currentZoomLevel);
         mCamera.setParameters(params);
         }
         }
         }); 
         }
         else
         zoomControls.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

add this in it's own layout called "custom.xml"

```
    <ZoomControls
    android:id="@+id/zoomControls1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp" />
```

If I help you in any way help me out and check out my youtube channel THANKS.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSdghmyCrOE?